# Rationality of $\log_b a$ when at least $a$ or $b$ is irrational and $a,b>1$

Tags: logarithms, irrational-numbers

> I am looking at the rationality of $\log_ba$ when at least $a$ or $b$ is irrational such that $a,b>1$ and neither of $a$ or $b$ is of the form $\left(\frac{e}{f}\right)^{(g/d)}$, where $d,e,f,\text{ and }g\in\mathbb{N}$.

I know how to check irrationality when both of $a$ and $b$ are rational, one of the beautiful answer by Gone is [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/656138/prove-that-log-2-3-is-irrational/656278#656278).

I am done with the case when exactly one of them is irrational.
Here my version of proof:

> W.L.O.G, Assume $a$ is irrational.
>   Suppose that $$\log_ba=p/q\enspace\text{ where } p,q\in\mathbb{N}\\\implies a^q=b^p$$
>   but $a^q$ is irrational and $b^p$ is rational. Hence, contradiction.

Also, if $a=b^c$, then it depends on $c$.

Finally, when $a$ and $b$ are irrational and $a\neq b^c$.

I have no idea about it. Can anyone help me with this? Also, is my above proof correct? If incorrect, please do provide the correct one. Thanks.

Comment: If $\log_b a = c$, then $a = b^c$.  So what do mean by "$a \ne b^c$"?

Comment: @RobertIsrael I want to say the other way round. It's if $a=b^c$ then $\log_ba=c$.

Comment: In your proof where exactly one is irrational, how do you know $a$ is irrational $\implies$ $a^q$ is irrational? Try $b=2, a= \sqrt{2}$.

Comment: Why is $a^p$ irrational? Say, you put $a=\sqrt{2}$ and $q=\text{even}$?

Comment: @Kumar yes, sorry I missed that.

Comment: @Kumar When you say $a \not = b^c$, is $c$ an integer or a rational number?

Comment: @healynr While, Thinking about it, I had in my mind that $c\in\mathbb{R}$ with simple examples of rational numbers and some irrational such as $\pi$, but as you ask the question, I am unable to decide it as I have no idea whether we can express $\mathbb{R}$ as a real power of some fixed irrational number? So, for cautionary purposes, I suppose we need to work with rational numbers only. :(

Comment: @Kumar Well if $a \not = b^c$ for some rational number $c$, then of course $\log_b a \not \in \mathbb{Q}$ since if it were, then $a = b^{\log_b a}$!

Answer (score 1):

If $a \not = b^c$ for $c \in \mathbb{Q}$, then $\log_b a = c \not \in \mathbb{Q}$. Now if we reduce the assumption to $c \in \mathbb{Z}$:

Let $a=\sqrt{\pi}$ and $b=\pi$. Then since neither $a,b$ are algebraic nor rational, they fit your assumption that neither equal $\left(\frac{e}{f}\right)^{(g/d)}$. 
$$\log_{b}a=\log_{\pi}\sqrt{\pi}=\frac{1}{2} \in \mathbb{Q}$$